# How to throw exception when try to mock gremlin query?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, gremlin

I'm trying to write unit test for a case when an exception is thrown but somehow it is throwing null instead of exception.

The service call that I'm trying to mock.

```
 private List<Vertex> getVertexList(final String vertexId, GraphTraversalSource graphTraversalSource, final int indexToLoop) {
        return graphTraversalSource.V(vertexId).repeat(in().dedup().simplePath()).until(loops().is(indexToLoop)).toList();
    }
```

I wrote the following to mock to throw Exception

```
 @Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private GraphTraversalSource gts;


  Mockito.when(gts.V(anyString()).repeat(any()).until((Predicate<Traverser<Vertex>>) any()).toList()).thenThrow(Exception.class);
```

Is there any way to mock this so that it throws exception? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `gts` and a call to `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in the `@Before` of the test, this style worked for me:

```
GraphTraversal v = mock(GraphTraversal.class);
GraphTraversal repeat = mock(GraphTraversal.class);
GraphTraversal until = mock(GraphTraversal.class);
when(gts.V(anyString())).thenReturn(v);
when(v.repeat(any())).thenReturn(repeat);
when(repeat.until((Predicate<Traverser<Vertex>>) any())).thenReturn(until);
when(until.toList()).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);
gts.V("test-id").repeat(out()).until(__.loops().is(1)).toList();
```

Depending on what you are doing you might consider avoiding the mock and just throwing an exception in the traversal itself:

```
GraphTraversalSource g = EmptyGraph.instance().traversal();
g.inject("test-id").sideEffect(x -> {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}).toList();
```

Obviously, that's a little different from what your mock is doing and does require the traversal to actually have data passing through it (hence my use of `inject()` to start the traversal rather than `V()` as `g` is bound to an `EmptyGraph` in this case.